# How to define global variables in Liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

Right now it seems variables I create can't communicate across files.

Answer (score 6):

It seems the templates are loaded before the theme, so variables set in your layout/theme file wont be present in templates. Frustrating. However you can set them via a snippet, and include this snippet in your templates, layout, etc

Comment: I like this solution as we can include this snippet only in the templates we need the variables.

Comment: Not only frustrating, it's ridiculous that Shopify Liquid is this awful. No global variables, no custom functions, no ability to create objects... Basically no ability to do anything. Shopify and liquid are both trash. But especially Liquid. Not to mention the awful state of the documentation. That said, 8 years later, your answer is still the only real option.

Answer (score 5):

For Liquid you can pass a variable in the include

```
{%- assign global_var = "VALUE" -%}
{%- include 'YOUR_FILE' global_var: global_var  -%}
```

For Shopify liquid you can do the following:

There is a work around this, you can set the global variable in the theme settings as an option `config/settings_schema.json`

```
  {
    "type": "text",
    "id": "global_variable",
    "label": "global variable",
    "default": "Variable value"
  },
```

and you can access it in the liquid files through

```
settings.global_variable
```

But the value is depending on what you enter in the theme settings.

If you need more dynamic way, you can set cart attributes through ajax like:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/cart/update.js',
      data: { attributes: {'global_variable': "MY_VALUE"} },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(cart) {
        location.reload();
      }
    });
```

And then access it any where in the theme through 
    cart.attributes.global_variable
But you have to update it each time the cart is empty

Answer (score 1):

In Liquid, as you want for example to determine the language and reuse this code in multiple occasions, you can create an file in the render folder.
instead of calling this using render, use include. Then it returns the assigned value. For example, create "render/current_language.liquid" :

```
{%- liquid
    assign current_language = 'en'
    if request.path contains '/nl/'
        assign current_language = 'nl'
    endif
%}
```

In a other file you can use as follows:

```
{%- liquid 
  include 'get-language' 
  if current_language == 'en'
    
  else

  endif
%}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use the

```
{% assign variable = value %}
```

you should be able to get the value anywhere in the file, and any file included after it has been assigned.

I believe this is the closest you can get to global variables in it.

Comment: It was accurate 2 and a half years ago - I haven't used it since end of 2016, so it might not be different now.

Comment: @dave4jr that is definitely wrong, they 100% have access to the parent context.  You can however provide custom variable values to snippets when including them to override the parent context.

Comment: @Dan, I deleted my comment by accident, but that's not true. I've just tested it right now again. Perhaps it's only in sections, but if you create a variable with assign at the top of the theme and then have a section right below it, you will NOT have access to it.

Comment: @dave4jr true - sections are sort of like self-contained modules with special scoping rules - this is by design - if you're trying to pass variables into sections you're attempting something wrong. I forget the exact contents of your comment, but I was talking about snippets.

Comment: @Dan, yeah my comment was saying that in order to get around it you can pass the variables from the parent context as arguments to the section. I think we were saying the same thing just differently. lol