# Setting URL variable for all posts

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, liquid

I'm trying to reference an image from a GitHub pages post. I have been referencing images from the layout, and to do so I have used the following code in my `_layouts/default.html`:

```
{% assign custom_url = site.url | append: site.baseurl %}
{% assign full_base_url = custom_url | default: site.github.url %}
… href="{{ "/images/logo.png" | prepend: full_base_url }}" …
```

(I'm not sure how exactly I ame up with the first two lines, but they seem to work well in both the live pages and my local preview so I'm inclined to keep their semantics.)

Trying to duplicate only the last row in the body of a post failed, leading to nothing being prepended. I assume that the variable is not present when the post gets rendered, only when that rendering gets plugged into the layout. Using all three rows in every post with images feels a bit repetitive.

I have read [Jekyll Front Matter Defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/front-matter-defaults/) which describes how to perform settings for all posts, but that does seem to only allow setting static values, not computed values like I do in my assignments.

I have also read [How to define global variables in Liquid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35094919/1468366) which seems to be addressing the same Liquid problem. But the question is very bare-bones, and tagged for Shopify not Jekyll so some of the answers don't feel applicable to me. The gist I get from the answers there is that maybe I might be able to include some “snippets” somehow somewhere, but I have no clue how to do that, let alone do that in a way that would not require adding lines to every post. The fact that the term “snippet” tends to refer to code snippets does not make searching for guides any easier.

Answer (score 1):

In one of my Jekyll project, I had the same kind of requirement and as you, I did not find a really clear way to do it.

I battled a long time trying to fit this into *_config.yaml*, but because of the processing order, realised it would never work.

What I finally ended up with is maybe not the cleanest of the solution, and I would really like someone coming with a better solution than this one, but here it is:

In the *_includes* folder I created a *variables.html* file containing all those *global variables* I knew I could use on all pages.

In your case the file *_includes/variables.html* would be

```
{% assign custom_url = site.url | append: site.baseurl %}
{% assign full_base_url = custom_url | default: site.github.url %}
```

Then in all the layouts I would need those variables, I would just include the *variables.html* files right after the `DOCTYPE`, here is a simplified example of *_layouts/default.html*:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% include variables.html %}
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        {{ content }}
        <a href="{{ '/images/logo.png' | prepend: full_base_url }}">Some image</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This way your variables `custom_url` and `full_base_url` are *globally*  accessible in everywhere you are using the *default* layout.

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to me the variables are now available neither in the layout nor in the post. At least on a local run.